# Wait for field change minimum pause time?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, announcements

I have created a workflow on the announcements list. The goal is to have announcements delete from the list once they reach the expiry date.

The workflow has the following steps:

- Wait for **Expires** to equal (ignoring time) **Today**
- Delete Item in **Current Item**

I know when you add a pause for duration step the minimum pause time is 5 minutes even if set to 1 minute within the workflow. But does this also apply to the Wait for field to change step?

I created a test record with expires set to today however in the workflow status it appears to not be getting past the "Waiting on expires" stage.

Refreshed the page every few minutes and there has been no change. Can anybody explain what's going wrong here or suggest a better way to achieve this goal?

Central Admin access is not an option so no power-shell solutions etc.

Thanks

Comment: How are you triggering your workflow? on which event?

Comment: This is set to trigger on both Item Creation and Item Modification.

Comment: It will not automatically check for dates, you have to schedule it. May be using IMS

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it wouldn't check for dates. What would be the best approach to achieving this within IMS? (Not very experienced in using this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to List settings, you will get Information management policy settings link

> Click on announcements content type-->Enable Retention-->Add a
>   retention stage-->Select a time period (when to run the action)-->
>   Select Action as "start a workflow"

Comment: I have tried the above but the workflow doesn't seem to be triggering. I have used the set up:

Time Period: Expires + 0 days
Action: Start a workflow
Start this workflow: Expired Remover

Workflow logic:
If Current Item:Expires equals Today
Delete item in Current Item

I'm assuming the issue is with setting the time period as + 0 days? I tried looking online to see if this was an acceptable value and wasn't really able to get a clear answer.

Comment: 0 days is fine i guess. wait till tomorrow for results. It should work!

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if they test records are gone tomorrow